# How to set up WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp

I have a WP8 phone, and WhatsApp is not working. The following message appears to me  every time I try to access the app:

> (Could not connect to WhatsApp. Please check your network settings and try again later.)

How can I solve this?

Comment: i am from Sudan, if that's helpful

Comment: does Internet Explorer work? can other apps use the internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

Please replace the `<your number>` and `<country code>` tags and put it on your browser. If this gives a bad message / error please contact your internet service provider.

```
https://v.whatsapp.net/v2/exist?in=<your number>&cc=<country code>
```